# Azure AD: include custom field in id_token

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect

I am using Azure Active Directory (OpenId-Connect flow) to authenticate users in my ASP.NET MVC web app. I would like to set a "structure" field on my users in the AD and be able to include it in the id_token provided when the user signs in, so that the application knows about it (this field is required for automatic user creation in the app).

Is it possible to do something like this with Azure AD? If not, is it possible to use an existing field like the department (which is also not included in the id_token) for that matter? If it's still not possible, is it possible to use something like the graph API to provide this information? (and how would you proceed to set this field from the AD, and retrieve it from the app?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today (2017-04-19) you cannot customise the ID Tokens.

But you can of course use the Graph API to get all and any information about the logged-in user and model your ClaimsPrincipal based on that. For example the [GetUser operation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/users-operations#GetAUser).

You can read more about the events [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/multitenant-identity/authenticate). And the one you are interested in is **AuthenticationValidated**

Comment: Extension properties for example are not passed in id tokens, but can be gotten by querying the user profile from the Graph.